# Custom HTML View for list part

Tags: web-part, custom-list

I am new to Sharepoint and am looking for some help.

I have a list of about 300 items and each item has a unique ID. I created a page that has a filter web part and a list-view connected to the filter. The list will always display one item.form.[image]

I need to display the one list result in a custom HTML as the one shown below

[image]

Comment: You can use SharePoint's REST API to pull the data from the list.  Then you'll have to use your standard HTML / CSS to do the rest.  Here's a good overview of SharePoint's REST API:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Comment: To manipulate list view web part I would suggest to use Client Side Rendering. Refer this link - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: Also refer this link. However you will have to create your own html snippet - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219969/show-list-items-in-custom-format-like-repeater-or-datalist-using-csr/220089#220089